# basic php5 file upload issue

Tags: php, file

I'm currently coding the most basic file upload to go to our server from an input type="file" attribute.  This is my HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register-complete.php" method="post">
        <h5>Register Now</h5>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" placeholder="Login Name"/><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Displayname" placeholder="Display Name"/><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="Email" /><br />
        <input type="radio" name="Paypal" value="1" /> This is my Paypal email.<br />
        <input type="radio" name="Paypal" value="0" /> I do not want payment. I wish to preserve anonymity.<br /><br />
        Avatar Picture: <br /><input type="file" name="AvatarPicture" id="AvatarPicture" />*500kb max file size.<br />*Accepted filetypes: .jpg, .png<br /><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description" placeholder="Account Description"/><br />
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="Password"/><br />
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="PasswordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password"/><br />
        <p class="text-center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" name="submit" /></p>
    </form>
```

Basically I'm just concerned with the AvatarPicture input, and just get it to upload a file to my server.  Here is the PHP code I have to do that.

```
$username = $_REQUEST["Username"];
$displayname = $_REQUEST["Displayname"];
$email = $_REQUEST["Email"];
$paypal = $_REQUEST["Paypal"];

$target_dir = "images/avipictures/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["AvatarPicture"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["AvatarPicture"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["AvatarPicture"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["AvatarPicture"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)) {
        echo "The file has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

This is literally the same exact thing as the w3schools code to the tee.  However I am receiving an internal server 500 error unless I change the "tmp_name" in the move_uploaded_file() to "name", which just leads to the else statement.  I've been messing around with this all day and I have just been tearing my hair out at just how simple this bit of code should be but doesnt seem to be at all.  Any ideas?  (Also, the file_uploads is set to on and the default largest file size is set to 50mb.)

Comment: I did check my logs.  I'm not 100% sure how to read them or what I am looking at.  I apologize I am a bit noobie at this.

Comment: That's accessible from the "logs" folder in your root usually. check your cpanel or whatever way your host has left you to look in. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. That will display notices on your screen instead.

Comment: you should also check out the manual on upload errors http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php and http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Darn was hoping your suggestions were going to work.  I am able to access the log file but it just seems to be regular POST and GET commands being sent to and from the server, nothing that seems to indicate an error.  Also when I did try to use the ["AvatarPicture"]["error"] echo and print_r it outputs a "0".

Comment: can you var_dump($_FILES["AvatarPicture"]) and post the result here?

Comment: It must be something wrong with the server configuration or the final two lines executing the upload.  This is the result I got: File is an image - image/jpeg.array(5) { ["name"]=> string(13) "LE-axwn5.jpeg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\php75FB.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(35334) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what the problem is without a decent log file, but it could be that the directory you're trying to write to doesn't exist or you don't have permission to write to it.  Are you sure that the images/avipictures/ directory that you're trying to write to exists, and that the webserver has permission to write to it?  If not, you'll need to create the directory and set the permissions on it such that the webserver can write to it.

Comment: I did ensure that the directory does exist.  I'm not sure if the webserver has permission to write to it but I will check my godaddy hosting.

Comment: I can at least provide the log file for the final series of characters, as it doesnt release any PII but does give some helpful information too.  I do like how the error is telling me that what i tried to do worked yet still retrieves a 500 internal server error.
those numbers are:
sc-status: 500
sc-substatus: 0
sc-win32-status: 0
sc-bytes: 1632
cs-bytes:36811
time taken:265

Comment: This was the answer.  my godaddy hosting wasn't configured to be able to write to that destination.  Thank you very much Andrew